# Could not GetActiveTransaction

Tags: repository, dbcontext, aspnetboilerplate

I need to call stored procedure in my App Service. I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1199648/Using-Stored-Procedure-User-Defined-Function-and-V) to create a custom repository. But I could not find the `Context.Database`.

Here is the code:

```
[UnitOfWork]
public virtual async Task<List<string>> GetUserNames()
{
    EnsureConnectionOpen();

    using (var command = CreateCommand("GetUsernames", CommandType.storedProcedure))
    {
        using (var dataReader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        {
            var result = new List<string>();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                result.Add(dataReader["UserName"].ToString());
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

What is the `Context.Database` and how do I use it?

My application is `MVC` in `.Net4.6.1`.

## Update 1

I have resolved this issue by inheriting `MyApplicationRepositoryBase`.

Now I face a new issue when trying to `GetActiveTransaction`. I don't have any idea about this. What can I do?

Here is the code:

```
private DbTransaction GetActiveTransaction()
{
    return (DbTransaction)_transactionProvider.GetActiveTransaction(new ActiveTransactionProviderArgs
    {
        {"ContextType", typeof(MyDbContext) },
        {"MultiTenancySide", MultiTenancySide }
    });
}
```

Here is the error log:

> ```
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  
> at Abp.EntityFramework.EfActiveTransactionProvider.GetActiveTransaction(ActiveTransactionProviderArgs args) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.EntityFramework\EntityFramework\EfActiveTransactionProvider.cs:line 21
> ```

## Update 2

I tried to comment out the `command.Transaction` and it worked:

```
private DbCommand CreateCommand(string commandText, CommandType commandType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    var command = Context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();

    command.CommandText = commandText;
    command.CommandType = commandType;
    // command.Transaction = GetActiveTransaction();

    foreach (var parameter in parameters)
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
    }

    return command;
}
```

I still need to put my code under a Transaction, so I don't want to comment out this line. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now I faced the new issue when trying to get Active Transaction

Add this in `PreInitialize` method of `YourProjectNameDataModule`:

```
Configuration.ReplaceService<IEfTransactionStrategy, DbContextEfTransactionStrategy>(DependencyLifeStyle.Transien‌​t);
```

Comment: I have three method in a unit of work. I'm calling a stored procedure on second method, it's executed but not in same transaction. I'm trying GetActiveTransaction, but null exeception has been occured like yours. Did you use replace service, if you do, which type to which type? Thanks @HoangTran

Comment: @OguzhanKIRCALI: I have replaced the service "IEfTransactionStrategy" with "DbContextEfTransactionStrategy". The same with Aaron's answer

Comment: @OguzhanKIRCALI You can check if any of the [previous versions of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47076796/revisions) are useful.

Comment: I resolved my issue. After inject unitOfWorkManager to my manager, i called unitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChangesAsync() at end of first method. It means; second method can see the change on object without commit. Thank you anyway for you help. @HoangTran